# Giving access to s3 having a specific "tag" using AWS IAM roles and policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

I want to create an AWS IAM Policy, such that the attached role should have access to all S3 buckets having the Tag , "Team = devops". I tried the following JSON file, but it wont work.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {"s3:ResourceTag/Team": "devops"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As per [Available Condition Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#AvailableKeys-iamV2), **s3:ResourceTag** is not available for S3 conditions.

> The predefined keys available for specifying conditions in an Amazon S3 access policy can be classified as follows:

As in [Object Tagging and Access Control Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html#tagging-and-policies), access control per object is possible with **s3:ExistingObjectTag** condition key.

> The following permissions policy grants a user permission to read objects, but the condition limits the read permission to only objects that have the following specific tag key and value.
>   
>   ***security*** : **public**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect":     "Allow",
      "Action":     "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":    "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Principal":   "*",
      "Condition": {  "StringEquals": {"s3:ExistingObjectTag/security": "public" } }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The docs have been reorganized since you wrote this 3 years ago.  A table documenting available condition keys for various types of objects is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/list_amazons3.html. I believe the version you quoted is archived at: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-s3-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/object-tagging.md

Answer (score 1):

This did not work. The only difference is the action was Deny in my case and I can confirm that did not apply!

```
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Sid": "TestPreventS3ObjectDeletion",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:ResourceTag/Protection": "True"
            }
        }
```