# Unable to add policy based on tags for s3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS and I have a scenario where i need to give access to s3 objects based on tags. I created IAM user and attached following policy to the user using my root account.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/role": "developer"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I have bucket with many files and tagged one file with tag `role` and value as `developer` so that my user can see only one file I tagged.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJmaR.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jyOl.jpg

But when i login with IAM user, I am not seeing any buckets. Ideally i expected i would see bucket with relevant file (file with right tag)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdWHS.jpg

I tried several other options, but none of the options worked. Another option I tried is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::general-eda/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/role": "developer"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong or should user have any other permissions so that tags will work as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Edit1: Based on comments I edited my policy but still not working

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/role": "developer"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you want them to see buckets you need to grant permission to ListAllMyBuckets (which does not support any conditions). They can list obscure without seeing the bucket by directly navigating to the right url in the browser.

Comment: I added one more statement ```  {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }```
Now iam seeing all buckets, but when i open bucket it says "Insufficient permissions to list objects"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your policy is basically saying "Allow this person to do *anything* on AWS as long as the object has a tag of `role:develop`".

However, very few API calls to AWS can use this Condition. They are: `DeleteObjectTagging`, `DeleteObjectVersionTagging`, `GetObject`, `GetObjectAcl`, `GetObjectAttributes`, `GetObjectTagging`, `GetObjectVersion`, `GetObjectVersionAcl`, `GetObjectVersionAttributes`, `GetObjectVersionTagging`, `PutObjectAcl`, `PutObjectTagging`, `PutObjectVersionAcl`, `PutObjectVersionTagging`

See: [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html)

Therefore, **any API call that is *not* one of the above will fail** due to the Condition in your IAM policy.

To list the contents of a bucket, you would need to grant `s3:ListBucket` permission to the user.

Comment: Thanks John. But we do have `GetObject` as part of API call. But why dont I see relevant files. Iam still seeing error `Insufficient permissions to list objects`
After code change as per comment to my question, I added one more statement `ListAllMyBuckets` as part of Action. Any help is appreciated. Final code is in my Edit1 of the posted question.

Comment: `ListAllMyBuckets` will allow you to list the names of the buckets (but not their contents). `GetObject` gives permission to retrieve the objects themselves. To obtain a **list of the object names**, you require `ListBucket` permission. It would be better named as "ListObjects", but due to history the permission is called `ListBucket` and relates to the `ListObjects` action. Please note that `ListObjects` cannot be restricted by Tag.

Comment: So what i understood is, it is not achievable to show only relevant files based on tags for IAM user? Because tags wont work for ListBucket and the user can see all objects inside bucket irrespective of tags? In that case, how do I enforce my IAM user sees only few files and not all in a bucket? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is also not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261740/giving-access-to-s3-having-a-specific-tag-using-aws-iam-roles-and-policy
It said invalid principle and i removed that key so that JSON is valid

Comment: That is correct. Users either have permission to list _all_ objects or _none_ of the objects. Tag-based rules can only be enforced on the actions listed above, such as `GetObject`. If your objects are organised in folders (directories), then you could instead enforce permissions that limit the ability to view particular folders. This would _not_ involve the use of Tags.

Comment: Thanks John. I think Iam ok with original solution. Though user is able to see all files, he wont be able to download files if tag condition fails. He will be able to download files with relevant tags. But here he would know what all files exists in that folder. I think iam ok with it. Iam accepting your answer.